# Angular 4 404 error - Call json file using http get method angular 4 webpack

Tags: json, angular, http, webpack

I have a local json file and trying to read from Http get method.The application throwing an exception on console(404). I have read if you use webpack the assets/data are not available as for the angular-cli.json. I'm using webpack. Do you know where to put the json file so it can be read?

```
import {IProduct} from './product.model';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    private productUrl = require('./product.json');

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
        return this._http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl)
            .do((data) => console.log('products: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

where product.json is in the same dir of the ProductService.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Well what is the path you are trying to use, and where is the file located in your structure?

Comment: I've updated my post with the code snipped I'm using

Answer (score 0):

---

**If using angular cli**

---

AFAIK there is one way to do this.

1. Save the file (say file.json) in assets folder.
2. In you angular-cli.json file, go to node: apps> assets and verify that name "assets" exists.

Now access:

http://localhost:[PORT_NUMBER]/assets/file.json

BTW, your web app should not be your api. Instead of consuming json file, create variables in your services.

Example:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class DataMockService {
    public GetObjects(): any {
        return {
            name: "nilay", ...
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not have an asset folder. The asset folder is usable only if you use angular-cli.json file. I'm using webpack.

Answer (score 0):

With webpack, no matter where you have stored your json file, you can access it from anywhere, but always starting from the `src` folder.

So it should look something like this:

```
return this._http.get<IProduct[]>('src/app/services/product.json')
```

i.e just mark the complete path to your json file starting from `src`.

Comment: It does not work, still : 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/main/webapp/app/layouts/product/products.json'

Comment: Have you checked and double checked that the path is correct? :)

Comment: If path is correct, it seems your structure is a bit different than usual, so then try and start from `webapp/app....`